# Android Updating value in sqlite based on Checkbox

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

I have a value in an sqlite table which updates depending on the state of the checkbox.
At the moment, the value does update, but only when I close the app. 
What I want is:

1. check checkbox
2. update value in the sqlite table
3. update/refresh view to display the updated value immediately

Also, I'm putting the checkbox listener in the adapter. Is this okay? If not, how do I use the listener on main activity?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

---

Here are some of the codes

adapter:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    db = new MyDatabase(context);
    final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,null);
    }
    convertView.setTag(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString());
    TextView value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);

    value.setText(String.valueOf(child.getValue()));

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    if(child.getValue() == 0)
    {
        cb.setChecked(true);
    }

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b == true)
            {
                String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
                db.updateIsChecked(id);
            }
            else
            {
                String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
                db.updateIsNotChecked(id);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

database:

```
public void updateIsChecked(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put("value", 0);
    db.update("table",newValues,"id =? ",new String[] {id});
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm putting the checkbox listener in the adapter. Is this okay? >>> **Yes It is OKAY**

Comment: Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

Your all code seems fine. What you need to do is try following code.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b)
        {
            String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
            db.updateIsChecked(id);
        }
        else
        {
            String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
            db.updateIsNotChecked(id);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

**Edit**

There is a good blog to handle "Checkbox" views inside list to maintain its state. Please look at [ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html). I also use this code to fix checkbox state issue.

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
    }
});
```

Comment: I did use notifyDataSetChanged(), but the value updates only after I reopen the app. With the if statement (if value 0, checked), I cannot uncheck the box since it just checks itself again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still not getting what I need. I've uploaded the code to github - https://github.com/Az35/test - it may provide better information in where I went wrong. I've applied what I gathered from the link you provided and it still has the same problem: sqlite database only updates when app is restarted, which leads to the problems with the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` in your `adapter` to update/refresh ListView.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
            db.updateIsChecked(id);
        } else {
            String id = String.valueOf(childPosition+1);
            db.updateIsNotChecked(id);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: I did use notifyDataSetChanged(), but the value updates only after I reopen the app. With the if statement (if value 0, check), I cannot uncheck the box since it just checks itself again.

Comment: Which part of the code should I show? Should I copy paste the whole adapter?

Comment: The part you think is relevant. @Az37